# Uniq skipping middle part of the line when comparing lines

Tags: linux, bash

Sample file

```
aa\bb\cc\dd\ee\ff\gg\hh\ii\jj

aa\bb\cc\dd\ee\ll\gg\hh\ii\jj

aa\bb\cc\dd\ee\ff\gg\hh\ii\jj
```

I want to skip 6th field 'ff' when comparing for an unique line, also I want the count of # of duplicate lines in front.

I tried this, without any luck:

```
sort -t'\' -k1,5 -k7 --unique xslin1 > xslout
```

Expected output

```
3 aa\bb\cc\dd\ee\*\gg\hh\ii\jj
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F'\' -v OFS='\' '{$6="*"} 1' xslin1 | sort | uniq -c
      3 aa\bb\cc\dd\ee\*\gg\hh\ii\jj
```

#### Discussion

With `--unique`, `sort` outputs only unique lines but it does not count them.  One needs `uniq -c` for that.  Further, `sort` outputs all unique lines, not just those that sort to the same value.

The above solution does the simple approach of assigning the sixth field to `*`, as you wanted in the output, and then uses the standard pipeline, `sort | uniq -c`, to produce the count of unique lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\\"} {$6="*"} uniq[$0]++{} 
       END {for (i in uniq) print uniq[i] "\t" i}' file
3   aa\bb\cc\dd\ee\*\gg\hh\ii\jj
```